# I am creating a dynamic form with react and useState but its not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am setting up a form with React and Hooks, I need React to create a dynamic form on the fly in to an array. How can I get this done? I am having trouble getting the forms to be created on the fly and also to get the values of the array.

this is a sample of the project code that i have tried to set up https://codesandbox.io/s/7m0ojl3okq

I want to be able to upload the static form and the dynamically created one to the server. different tables though. how would I achieve this. I can do this for the static form but not the one that would be created dynamically especially since I haven't gotten it to work. Thanks

Comment: The code sample shared has a lot going on. Would you be able to reduce what you're written above to one question? What is the first thing you're expecting to happen, that isn't happening?

Comment: I have tried to streamline the code. https://codesandbox.io/s/x79jy77j1o the first thing I want is to be able to input values in the fields and save them in the useState array

Comment: The feature described, fields updating state when they change, is already happening in the sandbox above. I'm moving on here because I don't understand the question. Check out Formik; it abstracts a lot of these questions/patterns away. https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik